# Como trasformar uma tabela HTML em um Data Frame

Tags: javascript, html, python, table

Estou tentando integrar um script em python com uma tabela HTML
Como posso fazer isso

segue minha tabela.

```
<table data-spy="scroll" class = "table-responsive-sm" id="table-prem"  >
                            <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: #e8e8e8;">
                                <th scope="col"  >CPF</th>
                                <th scope="col" >Nome</th>
                                <th scope="col" >Premio Base</th>
                                <th scope="col" >Falta Just.</th>
                                <th scope="col" >Falta Injut.</th>
                                <th scope="col" >Premio Final</th>
                                <th scope="col" >Observação</th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text"  id="cpf" ></td>
                                    <td><input disabled type="text" class="" id="nome_i"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="" id="premio_base"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" class="" id="falta_just" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" class="" id="falta_injus" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="" id="premio_final"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="" id="obs"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">deleta</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                       </table>
```

Comment: Comece fazendo o parse do HTML, extraindo as informações desejadas. Talvez o módulo `beautifulsoup` possa te ajudar nisso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possivel extrair os dados com o módulo **beautifulsoup** e anexar estes arquivos em um DataFrame ou em váriaveis.

O código abaixo extrai o titulo do arquivo e o armazena na variável titulo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
titulo = soup.title.string
```